# tkinter TclError item not found even though the object is created right before

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

So I am creating a GUI with Tkinter in Python which creates a lot of shapes and binds tags to them to make them clickable.

In a for loop that reads a csv file row by row, it calls a function `drawRect` which draws a rectangle then binds a tag/command to the <Button-1> event:

```py
    def drawRect(self, tag, x, y, width, height):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+width, y+height, fill='', width=3, tags=f"{tag}", outline="red")
        self.canvas.update()
        self.canvas.tag_bind(str(f"{tag}"), "<Button-1>", self.clicked)
```

The parameter `tag` is retrieved from the csv file.

So now to the problem... I have a function elsewhere which allows me to delete some of these rectangles and their corresponding entries (the entire row) in the csv file, which works flawlessly, and even deletes the empty row afterwards. This modified csv file is persisted till the next time the python script is ran, which then it again retrieves each row from the csv file and creates rectangles based on each row. However, the problem is that whenever I delete a certain entry, the next time I run the script, Tkinter tells me the item that is after the deleted shape is not found:

```
_tkinter.TclError: item "58" doesn't exist
```

Which doesn't make sense because I create the rectangle literally a line before I call `tag_bind`... I have checked that the tag being passed into drawRect indeed exists as an entry in the csv file and is the tag that comes after the item I deleted (I deleted the item with `tag = 57` in this case)

What might be the problem here?

**EDIT:**

The two rows in question are:

```
56,title,,- -,661.0,556.0,12.0,20.0
58,title,,- -,661.0,736.0,12.0,20.0
```

After item with tag 57 has been deleted.

Comment: can you share the csv file's 57th and 58th lines too. It may be helpful to debug this issue.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer, I've edited the question to include that

Comment: `58` is not a valid canvas item tag - they're required to not be entirely numeric, so that they can be distinguished from canvas item ID numbers.

Comment: I see... however, I'm creating these items within a loop and need to generate the tag numbers programmatically, which is why I've chosen to use numbers. Side note tho, the other interactions I've had with purely numeric tags have been fine so far

Comment: @jasonharper I will try an implementation with string tags tho, thanks for your suggestion